# Airflow error during celery execution

Tags: python, celery, airflow

We have an airflow setup with rabbitmq, mysql db and celery executor setup in a docker instance.
Trigerring the first individual step/opertator via a run command as below works.

```
airflow run wfm_model_training_client_1_queue_11 fetch_top_funnel_data  2016-03-03
```

However when we trigger the entire dag via a backfill command as below, we encounter the following error during celery execution. Clearly this is an error with celery, however how do i extract more logs to debug the same.

backfill command

```
airflow backfill wfm_model_training_client_1_queue_11 -s 2016-03-03 -e 2016-03-03
```

Celery error in celery_taskmeta table in traceback column

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 622, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 59, in execute_command
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
AirflowException: Celery command failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was due to some pickle related issue. I bypassed this issue by passing the --donot_pickle args to the backfill command.

It was resolved via the updated command

```
airflow run wfm_model_training_client_1_queue_11 fetch_top_funnel_data  2016-03-03 --donot_pickle
```

Comment: Is there a way to log celery command output to either the celery backend database or any logfile. I had to manually edit the celery python files to log the actual error to the DB